# Fitting DIV width to its internal text using width

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm trying to have multiple pieces of text next to each other and centered on the page. They're currently showing on the left unless the width of the div is changed. How would I make it so that the div matches the width of its contents or is there another way to center this on the page?

The HTML is this;

```css
.navigation-container {
width: auto;
display: inline-block;
margin: auto;
padding-left: auto;
padding-right: auto;
}

p {
font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
font-size: 1.5vh;
text-align: center;
padding-left: 1vw;
padding-top: 0vw;
padding-bottom: 0vw;
float:left;
color: #000000;
line-height: 0em;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation-container">
<p>Pg1</p> <p>Pg2</p> <p>Pg3</p> <p>Pg4</p> <p>Ph5</p>
</div>
```

The text will appear on the left of the page unless the container width is changed. How can I center all 5 pieces of this text?

Comment: Please see my answer below for a working Codepen. You should be using a list instead of `<p>` here. It's not good practice to be styling raw HTML elements like that.

Answer (score 0):

As your `.navigation-container` is a `inline-block` element, so you will need to use `text-align:center` to its parent element. In the snippet `body` is your parent element so try to add `text-align: center`. However the best way is to wrap your `.navigation-container` to an another div and apply `text-align: center` to it as `body` will affect the whole page.

Also `padding: auto` is an invalid value, so better to remove it.

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

.navigation-container {
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
  font-size: 1.5vh;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 1vw;
  padding-top: 0vw;
  padding-bottom: 0vw;
  float: left;
  color: #000000;
  line-height: 0em;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation-container">
  <p>Pg1</p>
  <p>Pg2</p>
  <p>Pg3</p>
  <p>Pg4</p>
  <p>Ph5</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `display: flex;` wrap or nowrap up to you, `justify-content: center` to center the text in the center. or you can use `text-align: center` for `display: inline-block;`

```css
.navigation-container {
width: auto;
display: flex;
flex-flow: row nowrap;
justify-content: center;
margin: auto;
padding-left: auto;
padding-right: auto;
}

p {
font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
font-size: 1.5vh;
text-align: center;
padding-left: 1vw;
padding-top: 0vw;
padding-bottom: 0vw;
float:left;
color: #000000;
line-height: 0em;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation-container">
<p>Pg1</p> <p>Pg2</p> <p>Pg3</p> <p>Pg4</p> <p>Ph5</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use another `div` element to center the the navigation div.  There are a number of ways of doing this, CSS Grid and Flexbox would be good to use in this instance, but I've provided you some code which is in keeping with the existing style of CSS you've already written.

There are a couple of background colours which I've left in which are there purely to visually show you what is happening with each `div` and you can just remove those lines when you're happy:

HTML:

```
<div class="nav-wrapper">
  <div class="navigation">
    <p>Pg1</p> <p>Pg2</p> <p>Pg3</p> <p>Pg4</p> <p>Ph5</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.nav-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
  text-align: center;
}
.navigation {
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
  font-size: 1.5vh;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 1vw;
  padding-top: 0vw;
  padding-bottom: 0vw;
  float:left;
  color: #000000;
  line-height: 0em;
}
```

And on JSBin:
http://jsbin.com/xiwanegohi/1/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example of what you need.
Use a list instead of paragraphs, it won't break the line and you won't need to add lots of odd styling.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QmRJZw

HTML:

```
<div class="navigation-container">
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.navigation-container {
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  text-align:center
}

.navigation-container ul li{
  display:inline-block;
  list-style:none;
  padding:7px 14px;
}
```